# Routing auto bundle unable to update

Tags: php, symfony, composer-php, symfony-cmf

I'm not a composer expert, and perhaps I don't understand some things about it.

There is new Symfony CMF version I wanted to use for learning it:
https://github.com/symfony-cmf/symfony-cmf/blob/master/composer.json

As you see in composer.json, there is requirement to use:

```
    "symfony-cmf/core-bundle": "1.1.*",
```

In routing-auto-bundle https://github.com/symfony-cmf/RoutingAutoBundle/blob/master/composer.json :

```
    "symfony-cmf/core-bundle": "1.0.*",
```

Does this difference stops me from using routing-auto-bundle? Or I can do something somehow with this? As mentioned, I'm still learning of composer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the CoreBundle didn't had BC breaks in 1.1.0, you can alias 1.1.0 to 1.0.0. That way, you install 1.1, but composer thinks it is 1.0. https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/aliases.md

It's not ideal, but since the routingautobundle is not stable yet, it's the only solution.

```
{
    "require": {
        "symfony-cmf/core-bundle": "1.1.* as 1.0.*"
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Actually the exact string do not works (error msg: "Could not parse version constraint 1.1.* as 1.0: Invalid version string "1.1.*" in "1.1.* as 1.0", the alias source must be an exact version"), but it worked with "dev-master as 1.0.0". By the way: is there some wise workflow with composer that allows quickly conclude what is needed? With several bundles dependencies I wasted quite a lot of time, checking if it works each time and waiting until composer update all packages...